# Calculate area of plane in 3D space using X, Y, Z

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I have a polygon that's positioned on the earth. For each point, I have:

The latitude in degrees (x)
The longitude in degress (y)
The altitude above sea level in meters.

An example of one of my points is  `{ x: 144.99533074458003, y: -32.39730248504104, z: 263.24070871460185 }`

Now, in my application, a user draws a polygon in space, and I need to determine the area of that polygon. The user could draw a polygon around a door, or a roof maybe. Sometimes even a sidewalk.

Once the user is done, I have a list of all the points they selected.

An example could be this:

```
DOOR = [
  { x: 144.99533074458003, y: -32.39730248504104, z: 263.24070871460185 }, // First point, bottom left
  { x: 144.99533197184215, y: -32.39730172327194, z: 267.1472276731874 }, // Top left
  { x: 144.99534689346532, y: -32.39726245542652, z: 267.04165748822226 }, // Top right
  { x: 144.99534752390096, y: -32.39726407569114, z: 263.24884951333394 }, // Bottom right
  { x: 144.99533074458003, y: -32.39730248504104, z: 263.24070871460185 }, // Last point, same as first to close the loop.
];
```

The issue now, is that I need to figure out the approximate area between all these points. I know that the polygon won't be perfectly flat, but I can even it out if needed to give an approximation.

**My current strategy is as follows:**

- Find the distance between each of the points using the [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#:%7E:text=The%20haversine%20formula%20determines%20the,and%20angles%20of%20spherical%20triangles.).
- Determine the height difference between the two points by subtracting `z2` from `z1`.
- Find the actual length of the line using Pythagorus.
- Get the angle of the line relative to the horizontal plane using `(Math.atan2(end.y - start.y, end.x - start.x) * 180) / Math.PI` (Please excuse the Javascript, that's what I'm working in).
- I then have a list of all the lengths and the angles of each line.
- I then convert each angle to Radians.
- Then I generate x and y values like this:

  ```
    endX = start.x + length * Math.cos(angle)
    endY = start.y + length * Math.sin(angle)
  ```
- This give me a list of the X.Y values of the points.
- I then calculate the area using [this formula](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html)

This strategy works when my plane is nearly horizontal, but as soon as I try use it on a vertical surface, I get incorrect results.

I guess there's a few questions here, and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This would need to work for any number of coordinates greater than 3, not only 4 sided polygons.

Thanks!

Comment: You said you get incorrect results when the polygon isn't lying on the horizontal, how do you check the actual area ?

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach would be calculating the projected area using the same formula you provided but ignoring the z-coordinate (let's call it $A_p$ for demonstration). Then you can calculate the area of the original polygon by multiplying $A_p$ by $\sec \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the polygon and the horizontal.

Comment: This looks promising. Let's say my area of the polygon is 10m², and the polygon is at 45deg from the horizontal plane, what would that formula look like?

Would it be `10 x arccos(45)`?

Comment: Sorry, check my last edit. It should be $10 \sec (45^{\circ})$ (considering 10 being the projected area)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. If someone draws a polygon that's exactly on the vertical plane, the area is essentially 0.

Comment: does it work in other cases ?